# console output of containers running in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-eks

some time ago i deployed a simple chat application in azure kubernetes service. It consists of an activemq, redis and two java spring containers. When i deployed them to the azure kubernetes service, i was always able to see the console output (Tomcat started on.. and so on) of the deployments.

Now i am trying to do the same on AWS EKS. I am unable to find the console outputs of my deployments. I want to see them, because some error happens when i try to connect to the activemq broker from my local client program. I am new to AWS, so it would be great if someone could tell me how or where to see the output/protocols for e.g. the jms-server deployment. Thank you.

[image: deployments in eks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way, IMO, to view the logs of your pods is by accessing your cluster using `kubectl`, this is the most common way to administer k8s clusters and will allow you to view logs across all of your pods as well as performing a lot of other administrative tasks.

You can follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html) to configure kubectl access to your cluster.

Once you can access the cluster using kubectl, you can use the `kubectl logs <pod_name>` command to see the logs of each pod.